# Problema ao tentar fazer uma query com PHP e MYSQL

Tags: php, mysql, sql

Estou tentando fazer uma *query* diretamente no arquivo PHP onde cria a conexão com o banco de dados. Esta *query* irá criar a minha tabela. O problema é que estou tentando referenciar a variável de conexão no *mysqli_query()* e ele não está sendo referenciado(acredito que seja este o problema). Fiz nesta estrutura porque estou fazendo fazendo Orientado a Objetos!

O erro que está dando é: **Warning: mysqli_query() expects parameter 1 to be mysqli, boolean given in...**

Segue o código:

```
<?php

class db{

    private $dbServer = "localhost";
    private $dbUser = "root";
    private $dbPassword = "";
    private $dbName = "sql_queries";
    private $conn;

    public function __construct(){
        $this->conn = mysqli_connect($this->dbServer, $this->dbUser, $this->dbPassword) or die("Não foi possível estabelecer a conexão com a base de dados! ".mysqli_error($this->conn));
        $this->conn = mysqli_select_db($this->conn, $this->dbName) or die("Não foi possível se conectar com o banco de dados! ".mysqli_error($this->conn));

        $this->setQuery();
    }

    public function getConn(){
        return $this->conn;
    }

    public function setQuery(){

        $sql = "CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS sql_queries.aluno(
            aluno_id INT NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
            nome_aluno varchar(255),
            dataNascimento_aluno date,
            nome_pai varchar(255),
            nome_mae varchar(255),
            RG_aluno char(10),
            cpf_aluno char(11),
            telefone_aluno char(10),
            celular_aluno char(13),
            CONSTRAINT PK_aluno PRIMARY KEY (aluno_id)
            );";

            $result = mysqli_query($this->conn, $sql);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

O problema é que você setou duas vezes o `$this->conn`:

```
$this->conn = mysqli_connect($this->dbServer, $this->dbUser, $this->dbPassword) or die("Não foi possível estabelecer a conexão com a base de dados! ".mysqli_error($this->conn));
$this->conn = mysqli_select_db($this->conn, $this->dbName) or die("Não foi possível se conectar com o banco de dados! ".mysqli_error($this->conn));
```

Deveria ser:

```
$this->conn = mysqli_connect($this->dbServer, $this->dbUser, $this->dbPassword) or die("Não foi possível estabelecer a conexão com a base de dados! ".mysqli_error($this->conn));
mysqli_select_db($this->conn, $this->dbName) or die("Não foi possível se conectar com o banco de dados! ".mysqli_error($this->conn));
```

Pois o `$this->conn` deve ser o resultado do `mysqli_connect`, pois irá conter o "`link`", a função `mysqli_select_db` é só para trocar de banco, na verdade você nem precisa dela, só se quiser trocar de banco durante a execução, você pode simplificar para isto:

```
public function __construct(){
    $this->conn = mysqli_connect($this->dbServer, $this->dbUser, $this->dbPassword, $this->dbName) or die("Não foi possível estabelecer a conexão com a base de dados! ".mysqli_error($this->conn));

    $this->setQuery();
}
```

Comment: Perfeito! Após fazer o que você falou deu certo!!! Eu não sabia que não precisava referenciar duas vezes, e que a função mysqli_select_db() apenas serve para trocar de banco! Manterei a dica em mente!

Comment: Guilherme, na verdade, nesta linha de código *$this->conn = mysqli_select_db* eu estou sobrescrevendo o "Link" com outro resultado... Por isso não funcionava certo?

Comment: @WesleyRedfield isso mesmo, mysqli_select_db não contém o link, ele só retorna true ou false, para dizer se vc conseguiu trocar o banco ou não.